# SignedJwtAssertionCredentials returns "AccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client"

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm developing a Python script for my employer that uses the Google API Python Client. However, I'm having a problem with OAuth authentication via the SignedJwtAssertionCredentials. The relevant code is as follows:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'abunchofmumbojumbo@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'key.p12'
USER_EMAIL = 'emailaccountusedtoaccessdeveloperconsole@gmail.com'

f = file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
  SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
  key,
  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 
  sub=USER_EMAIL)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('youtube', 'v3', http=http)
```

And this is what is returned by Python when I execute the code:

```
oauth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client
```

I've tried to search online for how I could solve this, but I can't find anything. My best guess is that I'm not passing the correct variables into SignedJwtAssertionCredentials, but I'm not entirely sure that's the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.